# SQL request with ORDER, DISTINCT and COUNT

Tags: php, sql

My table has 4 columns: id, name, ip, timestamp

I'm trying to get results as following: "Show me for each "name" the count of rows you have with distinct "ip", and non-distinct ip (the total)"

I'm using this table to store all clicks users did on some links and I want to show a top click: for each "name" the amount of users who did click, and the total amount of clicks for this "name".

Is that even possible in one SQL request ?

Comment: at the moment I have a simple request who gets the results ordered by timestamp : 
SELECT * FROM table ORDER by timestamp DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
select name
     , count(*) total_clicks
     , count(distinct ip) distinct_ppl
from table_name
group by name
order by name /* or by count(*) desc or count(distinct ip) desc */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top 10 clickers like this:

```
SELECT count(ip),* FROM table GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count(ip) LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I also like:
`SELECT TOP 10 count(ip),* FROM table GROUP BY ip ORDER BY count(ip);`

Comment: Thats mssql not mysql